# Boolean Logic Design - Reduction

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have the following function to be reduced/simplified.

F(A,B,C,D) = BC + (A + C'D') where ' denotes the complement

```
Here's my solution:

= BC + (A + C'D')'

= BC + (A + (C+D)

= BC + (A + C + D)

= BC + C + A + D

= C(B + 1) + A + D

= C*1 + A + D

= C + A + D
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The second step looks a little dubious.  Applying De Morgen's Law, the distribution should be to the entire expression `A + C'D'`, not the inner expression `C'D'`.  We have `(x + y)' = x'y'`, so it would become something like `(A')((C'D')')`?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: It looks like there are one or more typos in your question - is the original expression `F(A,B,C,D) = BC + (A + C'D')` or `F(A,B,C,D) = BC + (A + C'D')'` ? You also have at least one missing parenthesis.

Comment: My apologies. The function should actually be                     F'(A,B,C,D) = BC + (A + (CD)')

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @Krysten: Can you update with the answer so this question is not left here hanging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in traditional algebra, if you do something to one side of the equation, you must do it to the other side, including complementing. Here we state the original equation:

F'(A,B,C,D) = BC + (A + (CD)')

Since we have F' instead of F, my intuition tells me to complement both sides, but first I distribute the complement in the term (CD)' to make life easier in the long run:

F' = BC + (A + (C'+ D'))

Now we can complement both sides of the equation:

1: F = '(BC)'(A + (C'+ D'))      The OR becomes AND after distributing complement

Now let's distribute the complements inside just to see what we get:

2: F = (B'+ C')(A'(CD))

Now we can just distribute the right term (A'(CD)) over the two terms being OR'ed:

3: F = B' *(A'(CD))* + C' *(A'(CD))*

We see that the right term goes away since we have a CC' and thus we are left with:

4: F = A'B'CD

Hopefully I didn't make a mistake. I know you've found the answer, but others reading this might have a similar question and so I did it out to save duplicate questions from being asked. Good Luck!