# How do I compare UITextfield input to different strings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextfield

I want to compare the value of the input from a UITextfield to some other strings. Here's my guessing.

```
if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"First" || @"Second" || @"Third"]) {
    // do something
}
```

Is there any better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation where you have a series of objects such as your example, you would add then to an array and test its existence in the array:

**Example**

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[arr addObject:@"First"];
[arr addObject:@"Second"];
[arr addObject:@"Third"];

if ([arr containsObject:textField.text])
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much clearer way to do it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help!  Although slightly related, does bring up an interesting topic for another thread regarding reducing boolean logic.

Comment: This might be a starter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147992/boolean-logic-design-reduction

Answer (score 4):

Put the ors in the right place:

```
if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"First"] || 
   [textfield.text isEqualToString:@"Second"] || 
   [textfield.text isEqualToString:@"Third"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add First, Secound and Third to an array and then

```
if([myarray containsObject:someObject]){
// I contain the object
}
```

This approach saves you time and code ;)