# iOS : compare UITextView Text with NSString Text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function in my code where I want to find out if the content of `UITextView` (resultText.text) is the same as one of the ticket numbers in the array `_feeditems`.

Here is the function.

```
-(void) findContact
{

    for (Tickets *tick in _feedItems){

       if ((resultText.text == tick.ticketNumber)){

          status.text = @"Match found";}

            else {

              status.text = @"Match nof found";}

    }
}
```

Need guidance on this one. Thank You.

Comment: You're asking this question for the third time! Read the documentations and previously asked questions and the answers to them.

Comment: also same one is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717789/how-do-i-compare-uitextfield-input-to-different-strings

Comment: I have looked at previously asked questions and the answers, but I have not found them helpful....perhaps I didn't get something...

Comment: And if do understand some of it and want to ask a question about it, then I am prohibited because I need 50+ points.....

Comment: So you are not helping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare with `isEqualToString` not with the operator

```
 if ([resultText.text isEqualToString: tick.ticketNumber]){
     // .....
}
```

Comment: ((resultText.text isEqualToString:(tick.ticketNumber))) ?

Comment: this should be in the Expression, mean `[Expression]` - `[resultText.text isEqualToString: tick.ticketNumber]`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing string is easy with isEqualToString: your code will be

```
-(void) findContact
    {
        for (Tickets *tick in _feedItems){

           if ([resultText.text isEqualToString:tick.ticketNumber]){

              status.text = @"Match found";}

                else {

                  status.text = @"Match nof found";}

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah yeah....but there are multiple instances of ticketnumber, and I want check if resultText.text matches one ore them....now I only get "Match not found" even if I typed in a ticket number I have saved...

Comment: How can I loop through the ticketnumbers and look for one specific number that isequalto resultText.text?